# Python: can't upgrade pip to version 9.0.1 (spyder)

Tags: python, pip, upgrade, spyder

I've been trying to install some packages like pygame and metatrader for python. when I try to, it get asked to upgrade my version. 
when I try that, the following happens

```
C:\Users\USER>pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-8.1.2:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 538, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Toegang geweigerd: 'c:\\programfiles\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pip' -> 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-46ifh8km-uninstall\\program files\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pip'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 736, in install
requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
renames(path, new_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 267, in renames
shutil.move(old, new)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 550, in move
rmtree(src)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 488, in rmtree
return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 383, in _rmtree_unsafe
onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 381, in _rmtree_unsafe
os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Toegang geweigerd: 'c:\\program files\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\basecommand.py'

You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

After I tried it just gives the same message again. I've been trying to install some packages like pygame and metatrader for python

Comment: Try opening the cmd command prompt as administrator and then try installing the package again. (right click cmd.exe and select run as administrator)

Comment: Have you tried running `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` like it says at the end instead of just `pip install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: yes I have, and that yields the exact same result I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue.

the problem was that within spyder I tried to upgrade pip instead of:

```
conda upgrade spyder
```

I had to remove the full anaconda installation and reinstall it.

so never try to

```
pip install
```

in the spyder prompt!

Answer (score 0):

In the linux world you need to have sudo rights to upgrade pip. This probably is also the case in windows (where it is called administrator rights).
I seldom fiddle with pip on the base system but either work in virtualenv or containerize the application using docker. That way you keep a lean and mean python on your computer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm afraid I'm just a beginner programmer and I don't really understand how to execute your explanation? . I've read about sudo elsewhere and my command prompt wasn't familiar with that, I guess because I do have windows

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using sudo rights to upgrade pip.Then it works.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Another great solution for python and metatrader, check this:

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

import io

TZ_SERVER = 'Europe/Tallinn' # EET
TZ_LOCAL  = 'Europe/Budapest'
TZ_UTC    = 'UTC'

class Pytrader_API:             
  
    def __init__(self):
        self.socket_error: int = 0
        self.socket_error_message: str = ''
        self.order_return_message: str = ''
        self.order_error: int = 0
        self.connected: bool = False
        self.timeout: bool = False
        self.command_OK: bool = False
        self.command_return_error: str = ''
        self.debug: bool = False
        self.version: str = '1.06'
        self.max_bars: int = 5000
        self.max_ticks: int = 5000
        self.timeout_value: int = 60
        self.instrument_conversion_list: dict = {}
        self.instrument_name_broker: str = ''
        self.instrument_name_universal: str = ''
        self.date_from: datetime = '2000/01/01, 00:00:00'
        self.date_to: datetime = datetime.now()
        self.instrument: str = ''

    def Set_timeout(self,
                    timeout_in_seconds: int = 60
                    ):
        """
        Set time out value for socket communication with MT4 or MT5 EA/Bot.
        Args:
            timeout_in_seconds: the time out value
        Returns:
            None
        """
        self.timeout_value = timeout_in_seconds
        self.sock.settimeout(self.timeout_value)
        self.sock.setblocking(1)
        return

    def Disconnect(self):
        """
        Closes the socket connection to a MT4 or MT5 EA bot.
        Args:
            None
        Returns:
            bool: True or False
        """

        self.sock.close()
        return True

    def Connect(self,
                server: str = '',
                port: int = 2345,
                instrument_lookup: dict = []) -> bool:
        """
        Connects to a MT4 or MT5 EA/Bot.
        Args:
            server: Server IP address, like -> '127.0.0.1', '192.168.5.1'
            port: port number
            instrument_lookup: dictionairy with general instrument names and broker intrument names
        Returns:
            bool: True or False
        """
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setblocking(1)
        self.port = port
        self.server = server
        self.instrument_conversion_list = instrument_lookup

        if (len(self.instrument_conversion_list) == 0):
            print('Broker Instrument list not available or empty')
            self.socket_error_message = 'Broker Instrument list not available'
            return False

        try:
            self.sock.connect((self.server, self.port))
            try:
                data_received = self.sock.recv(1000000)
                self.connected = True
                self.socket_error = 0
                self.socket_error_message = ''
                return True
            except socket.error as msg:
                self.socket_error = 100
                self.socket_error_message = 'Could not connect to server.'
                self.connected = False
                return False
        except socket.error as msg:
            print(
                "Couldnt connect with the socket-server: %self.sock\n terminating program" %
                msg)
            self.connected = False
            self.socket_error = 101
            self.socket_error_message = 'Could not connect to server.'
            return False

    def Check_connection(self) -> bool:
        """
        Checks if connection with MT terminal/Ea bot is still active.
        Args:
            None
        Returns:
            bool: True or False
        """

        self.command = 'F000#0#'
        self.command_return_error = ''
        ok, dataString = self.send_command(self.command)

        try:
            if (ok == False):
                self.command_OK = False
                return False

            x = dataString.split('#')

            if x[1] == 'OK':
                self.timeout = True
                self.command_OK = True
                return True
            else:
                self.timeout = False
                self.command_OK = True
                return False
        except:
            self.command_return_error = 'Unexpected socket communication error'
            self.command_OK = False
            return False

    @property
    def IsConnected(self) -> bool:
        """Returns connection status.
        Returns:
            bool: True or False
        """
        return self.connected

    def Get_static_account_info(self) -> dict:
        """
        Retrieves static account information.
        Returns: Dictionary with:
            Account name,
            Account number,
            Account currency,
            Account type,
            Account leverage,
            Account trading allowed,
            Account maximum number of pending orders,
            Account margin call percentage,
            Account close open trades margin percentage
        """
        self.command_return_error = ''

        ok, dataString = self.send_command('F001#0#')
        if (ok == False):
            self.command_OK = False
            return None

        if self.debug:
            print(dataString)

        x = dataString.split('#')
        if x[0] != 'F001':
            self.command_return_error = str(x[2])
            self.command_OK = False
            return None

        returnDict = {}
        del x[0:2]
        x.pop(-1)

        returnDict['name'] = str(x[0])
        returnDict['login'] = str(x[1])
        returnDict['currency'] = str(x[2])
        returnDict['type'] = str(x[3])
        returnDict['leverage'] = int(x[4])
        returnDict['trade_allowed'] = bool(x[5])
        returnDict['limit_orders'] = int(x[6])
        returnDict['margin_call'] = float(x[7])
        returnDict['margin_close'] = float(x[8])

        self.command_OK = True
        return returnDict

    def Get_dynamic_account_info(self) -> dict:
        """
        Retrieves dynamic account information.
        Returns: Dictionary with:
            Account balance,
            Account equity,
            Account profit,
            Account margin,
            Account margin level,
            Account margin free
        """
        self.command_return_error = ''

        ok, dataString = self.send_command('F002#0#')
        if (ok == False):
            self.command_OK = False
            return None

        if self.debug:
            print(dataString)

        x = dataString.split('#')
        if x[0] != 'F002':
            self.command_return_error = str(x[2])
            self.command_OK = False
            return None

        returnDict = {}
        del x[0:2]
        x.pop(-1)

        returnDict['balance'] = float(x[0])
        returnDict['equity'] = float(x[1])
        returnDict['profit'] = float(x[2])
        returnDict['margin'] = float(x[3])
        returnDict['margin_level'] = float(x[4])
        returnDict['margin_free'] = float(x[5])

        self.command_OK = True
        return returnDict

    def Get_PnL(self,
                    date_from: datetime = datetime(2021, 3, 1, tzinfo = pytz.timezone("Etc/UTC")),
                    date_to: datetime = datetime.now()) -> pd.DataFrame:
        '''    
        Retrieves profit loss info.
        Args:
            date_from: start date
            date_to: end date
        Returns: Dictionary with:
            realized_profit             profit of all closed positions
            unrealized_profit           profit of all open positions
            buy_profit                  profit of closed buy positions
            sell_profit                 profit of closed sell positions
            positions_in_profit         number of profit positions
            positions in loss           number of loss positions
            volume_in_profit            total volume of positions in profit
            volume_in_loss              total volume of positions in loss
        '''
        total_profit = 0.0
        buy_profit = 0.0
        sell_profit = 0.0
        trades_in_loss = 0
        trades_in_profit = 0
        volume_in_loss = 0.0
        volume_in_profit = 0.0
        commission_in_loss = 0.0
        commission_in_profit = 0.0
        swap_in_loss = 0.0
        swap_in_profit = 0.0
        unrealized_profit = 0.0
```

this example taken from [Pytrader for Metatrader](https://github.com/TheSnowGuru/PyTrader-python-mt4-mt5-trading-api-connector-drag-n-drop) API